# is there a way to tell if an nsmanagedobject is in a context but is not part of any or a specific relationship?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

For example, say I have the following entities:

- **Person**
- **House**
- **Car**

And a person can have many houses and cars, while cars and houses can only have one owner.

Now consider the following scenario:

1. I insert a person into the context, along with 3 houses and 3 cars.
   Out of these houses and cars, one house and one car already have an
   owner.
2. Then, out of the remaning 2 houses and 2 cars, I add one of each to
   the only inserted person.
3. At this point, if I save the context it'll reflect 3 houses and 3
   cars in context.insertedObjects. But I only want to save the objects
   that are reachable through the one person I have a handle to (the
   idea being that for the house and car with a previous owner, that
   owner person is probably a fault and I never fetched it.)

Sure I can manually delete these objects before saving, but I'm wondering if I can come up with a generalized solution, considering object reachability from a particular object.

Essentially something along the lines of (pseudo code):

```
for (NSManagedObject *obj in context.registeredObjects) {
    if (Person does not reach obj in any relationship ) {
        [context deleteObject:obj];
    }
}
```

By generalized solution I mean something not requiring knowledge of relationships and specific entities (so as not to iterate over a person's houses and cars relationship for every house and car).

Comment: Can you make the `house` & `car` relationship with `person` non-optional so the save will fail for the objects that have no owner.

Comment: I don't think that would work; that would also force me to set an owner when creating house and cars. The idea is to be able to create orphan cars and houses, keep them around in the context, and only just before save, remove any objects which are still floating in the context but are orphans as far as reachability from a person.

Comment: I think Rog's suggestion would work. You can have objects around in the context that are incomplete -- that is, that have required properties which are empty. It's only when you save the context that the non-optional rules kick in and the save fails -- which is what you want.

Comment: I gave it a try and got a an exception cause of the relationship being nil. Maybe it was only indirectly related (though that's why I replied what I replied). But regardless, failing to save would not be enough. Those objects would still be in the context unless I explicitly delete them by knowing which entities they belong to and that they are not reachable through specific relationships in person. I'm wondering whether I can delete them in a generic way

Comment: I still think this is the best way for you to go. You can deal with the validation issue directly on the `NSManagedObject` level by subclassing and overriding the `-(BOOL)validateForInsert:(NSError**)error` method. Check the relationship within that method and if it returns nil you know you can delete that object. Here's a bit more reading for you https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html

Comment: @Rog would you like to post this as an official answer so I can select it?

Comment: Sure thing, all done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `house` & `car` relationship with `person` non-optional so the save will fail for the objects that have no owner.

You can deal with the validation issue directly on the `NSManagedObject` level by subclassing and overriding the `-(BOOL)validateForInsert:(NSError**)error` method.

Check the relationship within that method and if it returns nil you know you can delete that object.

Here's a bit more reading for you https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html